# Crate DB how to set the parameter "wait_for_active_shards" when create a table?

Tags: elasticsearch, crate, cratedb

I set up a crateDB cluster of 5 nodes. And the situations are as follows:

1. (the `number_of_replicas` is 2, the `wait_for_active_shards` is "all") When one node down, the write process will report an error: Not enough active copies to meet shard count of [ALL] (have 2, needed 3).
2. (the `number_of_replicas` is "0-4", the `wait_for_active_shards` is "all") when one down, all fine. But while it is recovering, the write process will report an error: Not enough active copies to meet shard count of [ALL] (have 4, needed 5).

So, how can I set the `wait_for_active_shards` or the `number_of_replicas` to make sure that when at least one nodes down will not influence the cluster and the write process?

P.S. Is there any formula to calculate the value of this parameter

```
"wait_for_active_shards" like "int( (primary + number_of_replicas) / 2 ) + 1" ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the number of `wait_for_active_shards` to the `number_of_replicas`.
see our documentation here: https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/sql/statements/create-table.html#write-wait-for-active-shards